# Angular reactive forms custom validator. Enable Validation only when checkbox checked

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms

I have a problem validating the checkbox that are marked only. At first, when the component is initialize and all checkbox are disabled, if they click the save button it should output a validation that says you didn't click any checkbox. Second validation is when you have mark a checkbox but you didn't enter any quantity, it should only mark that "This field is required". Now however, when i click the save button, all quantity even though is disabled, the error "This field is required" is appearing. How can i solve this? Please also my commented functions, maybe this will help. Thanks.

Please click here for my stackblitz link : [CODE LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/enable-when-checkbox-is-check-in-reactive-forms-hwy7zb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
patchValues() {
    let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    this.orders.forEach(material => {
      material.materials.forEach(x => {
        rows.push(this.fb.group({
          checkbox_value: [null],
          material_id: new FormControl({ value: x.id, disabled: true }, Validators.required),
          material_name: x.name,
          quantity: [null]
        }));
        // this.formArrayLength++;
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create [custom validators](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator/) for you form and subforms in array.

For form its valid when one of checkboxes checked. And looks like

```
formValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
   return control.value.rows.some(i => i.checkbox_value) ? null : { 'checkboxReq': 'Some checkbox field is required' }
}
```

Add it to you form

```
this.myForm.setValidators([this.formValidator.bind(this)])
```

In template you can get it with `myForm.getError('checkboxReq')`

```
<small class="form-text text-muted danger">{{myForm.getError('checkboxReq')}}</small>
```

For subform need another validator

```
subFormValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
   return control.value.checkbox_value ? { 'req': 'This field is required' } : null
}
```

Add it when you init you subForm

```
(this.fb.group({
      checkbox_value: [null],
      material_id: [{ value: x.id, disabled: true }],
      material_name: x.name,
      quantity: [null]
    }, [this.subFormValidator.bind(this)]));
```

Template

```
<small class="form-text text-muted danger" *ngIf="row.invalid && row.touched">This field is required</small>
```

[**stackblitz example with changes**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/enable-when-checkbox-is-check-in-reactive-forms-ashtck?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hi and thank you for this. I have a problem with my patchValues function. Can you not change my patchValues since on my own app it says this.data.reduce is not a function. Can you return to how my patchValues would be? Thank you

Comment: reduce is default array method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) i use because i want to flat inner array. If you dont have inner array just remove reduce. Useing reduce and map is better than use forEach and push.

Comment: and also i have implemented my custom validator that says quantity should not more than available quantity and i don't know how i can combine it with your custom validator. Can you help with that. Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/enable-when-checkbox-is-check-in-reactive-forms-mysnf9?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Validators added in array. Just add you validator after my `[this.formValidator.bind(this), this.anotherFormValidator.bind(this)]`

Comment: Hello did you get it?